# Why aren't sql dates getting compared?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I am comparing dates and times but it doesn't work properly sometimes

**Code:**

```
Select nit_no, workno, convert(datetime,convert(varchar,w.ExpiryDate,106) +  ' ' + w.ExpiryTime), getdate()
from works w
where NIT_No= 3594 and WorkNo=1
and convert(datetime,convert(varchar,w.ExpiryDate,106) +  ' ' + w.ExpiryTime) <= getdate()
```

**Values:**

```
convert(datetime,convert(varchar,w.ExpiryDate,106) +  ' ' + w.ExpiryTime)= 2017-06-08 16:50:54.000  
getdate()= 2017-06-08 17:50:54.000
```

*ExpiryDate* is of **DATE** type and *ExpiryTime* is of type **VARCHAR**

It doesn't work properly, getdate() is less than another expression and stills returns the data.

**Update:**
What I am trying to do is comparing ExpiryDate and ExpiryTime with current Datetime i.e. Getadate(), if expiry date and time is less than current datetime then it shouldn't be displayed else displayed.

Comment: You shouldn't have to explicitly convert dates to compare them to strings btw.

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results are helpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff nothing special. Just what I posted is what I am trying to do, comparing ExpiryDate and time with current, if it's less than current datetime then it shouldn't be displayed else displayed

Comment: it's not less in values. IT"S MORE. 17:50 is after 16:50. That's why it returns data.

Comment: @Whencesoever but what about date ? date is less.

Comment: Can u share simple query without table column reference with dummy data

Comment: @Covert 2017-06-08 17:50:54.000 >= 2017-06-08 16:50:54.000  that's why that is true. I don't know what You don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting to characters and converting back, just convert the `expirytime` to a `time` data type, and add that time to a `expirydate` that is converted to `datetime` like so:

```
select *
  , expirydatetime = dateadd(millisecond
        ,datediff(millisecond,0,convert(time(7),w.expirytime))
        ,convert(datetime,w.expirydate)
      )
from works w
where dateadd(millisecond
        ,datediff(millisecond,0,convert(time(7),w.expirytime))
        ,convert(datetime,w.expirydate)
      ) < getdate()
```

or for use with `datetime2`

```
select *
  , expirydatetime2 = dateadd(millisecond
        ,datediff(millisecond,0,convert(time(7),w.expirytime))
        ,convert(datetime2(7),w.expirydate)
      )
from works w
where dateadd(millisecond
        ,datediff(millisecond,0,convert(time(7),w.expirytime))
        ,convert(datetime2(7),w.expirydate)
      ) < sysdatetime()
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/LDY81881

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
convert(datetime,convert(varchar,w.ExpiryDate,121) +  ' ' + w.ExpiryTime, 121 )
```